# Navigation bumps below header randomly

Tags: html, css, header

I have no idea what is going on here but if you go to the site I'm working on here `LINK: 54.191.89.210` and refresh a few times you'll see on occasion the navigation will load in the header on the right and other times it will create a white space below the header and load underneath. PIC (http://s11.postimg.org/7aozzs943/Screen_Shot_2014_08_27_at_2_55_38_PM.png) What in the world is going on?

Here is my header HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="home-menu pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal pure-menu-fixed">
        <a class="pure-menu-heading" href=""><img class="pure-img logo" src="img/logo.svg" width="250px"></a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speaking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Os</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Public Statements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      <div class="cf"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
    .pure-menu-fixed {
        position: relative;
    }

    .home-menu.pure-menu.pure-menu-open.pure-menu-horizontal.pure-menu-fixed {
        height: 150px;
        background: #7c0e0e;
    }

    .pure-menu.pure-menu-horizontal>ul li a {
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .pure-menu.pure-menu-horizontal>ul li a:hover {
        background: transparent;
        color: #a18d36;
    }

    .pure-menu.pure-menu-horizontal>ul {
        float: right;
        line-height: 150px;
    }

    .pure-menu.pure-menu-horizontal>ul li:last-child {
        margin-right: 100px;
    }

    .pure-menu.pure-menu-horizontal>ul li:nth-child(n+2)  {
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    a.pure-menu-heading {
        line-height: 140px;
    }

    img.logo {
        margin: 23px 0 0 100px;
    }

    .pure-menu li a {
        padding: 5px 40px;
    }
```

Comment: Here is the linkable domain http://54.191.89.210 - it didn't let me use it up there because it's alphanumeric as I'm just building it on AWS and don't have a domain name for it yet.

Comment: I refreshed the page 15 or 20 times and couldn't replicate your issue. What browser are you using? I only noticed what you say once I resize the browser

Comment: It does it with both Chrome and Safari for me. Here is a screenshot of it when it breaks - http://s11.postimg.org/7aozzs943/Screen_Shot_2014_08_27_at_2_55_38_PM.png

Comment: Out of curiosity, when it does that behavior, does it load completely? Because I noticed the site is quite slow (at least for me in Argentina), so maybe it's still loading when you see that

Comment: Yes, it all loads. It's very quick for me here in Canada. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.. had to add `display:table` for some reason to the UL.. anyways, working now!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it's random, but this file:

```
http://54.191.89.210/css/A.style.css.pagespeed.cf.m6uWtqO1vC.css
```

is overriding your height for .home-menu.pure-menu.pure-menu-open.pure-menu-horizontal.pure-menu-fixed (?!) with 100px instead of 150px, I'm guessing that's not enough vertical space to contain your ul so it moves down.

If you sort that out maybe you won't have the issue any more.

Comment: That's not it.. that's a media query for when it gets smaller.